# java constructor to make already correct subclasses

Tags: java, object, constructor, architecture

I have a class hirachy like:

```
class Main{
    Main(Object input){ /*   */}
}

class SubA extends Main{ 
   SubA(Object input){  
     super(input);
    // ...
    }
}

class SubB extends Main{ 
   SubB(Object input){
       super(input);
       // ...
    }

}
```

What I'm trying to impement is, that the constructor of `Main`already constructs a subclass depending in the inputparameters. Something like:

```
// Non working example
class Main{
    Main(Object input){

    if (input.fullfillsSomeCond()) { return new SubA(input); }
    if (input.fullfillsSomeOtherCond()) { return new SubB(input); }

    }
}
```

This is obvoiously not working, since I'll generate infinite loops due to recursion. Is there a better architecture witch allows that
`Main somthing = new Main(myInput);` already constructs the correct subclass?

Comment: I believe that it is impossible to allow a superclass to generate a subclass type depending on conditions specified in the superclass. Look at the factory pattern perhaps - it is a well known pattern and is used to create specific implementations (including subclasses) from a set of possiblities: [factory pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Factory_method_pattern)

Comment: It's not possible to return anything in a constructor. Take a look at the [factory pattern](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/design_pattern/factory_pattern.htm). Meaning: Don't use the constructor, but rather a factory's method.

Comment: Al least, you are trying to return a value from constructor! It is impossible in java

Comment: You actually **cannot** use the CTOR for that. Use the Factory Pattern. "This is obvoiously not working, since I'll generate infinite loops due to recursion." - No. It's because you cannot return anything from a constructor.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is impossible to do this utilizing the Constructor, but you could use a Factory Method:

```
class Main{
    Main(Object input){}

    public static Main create( Object input ) {
        if (input.fullfillsSomeCond()) { return new SubA(input); }
        if (input.fullfillsSomeOtherCond()) { return new SubB(input); }
        // You might want to handle the case where input does not 
        // meet any of the above criteria.
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("input must be either A or B!");
    }
}
```

Usage:

```
// Instead of new Main( input ):
Main oMain = Main.create(myInput);
```

Along with that you may want to make `Main` abstract and its CTOR `protected`.

Drawback here is that `Main` has to "know" about its subclasses and the conditions. But that were the case, too if it could be done through ctor.

Comment: This is probably the cleanest approach to the presented problem

Comment: Ok. I'll use this pattern. Thanks.